# How to open and view .schema files?

Tags: mysql

How to open and view .schema files?
I was told I can open this file on MySQL, but I only have an experience running MS SQL server virtually that is already set up by 3rd party. Any help would be appreciated.
Which platform should I use? I've tried mysql bench, but no luck so far.
I currently using Mac.

I don't know where to start because I'm an absolute beginner.

Comment: Have you tried to open any of these files with plain-text editor ?

Comment: If you are using Workbench you are in the right ballpark... Try importing it perhaps?  Or it is a remote DB and not one you can touch the drive with your hands?

Comment: Here is the thing .. it starts with setting up a connection to the schema .. (user / password) and if you have that, you should be able to see the schema to connect to it and then any tables it has etc..